# Why the AVERAGE function works but MEDIAN throws an error?

Tags: powerbi, dax

I am creating a calculated column in PowerBI and am having an issue with the MEDIAN function.  Here is my column :

```
MEAN Lead Time = 
VAR PartNumber = 'MyTable1'[Part#]
RETURN
CALCULATE(MEDIAN('MyTable2'[Lead Time]),FILTER('MyTable2','Lead Times'[Part#] = PartNumber))
```

When I run this code I get the error: Expressions that yield variant data-type cannot be used to define calculated columns.

However, if I change my expression from MEDIAN to AVERAGE it runs no problem.  But I want Median not Average, so I am not sure what I need to do...

Thanks in advance!

Comment: ["When `Expression` returns an Integer, the resulting data type of `MEDIANX` is `Variant` (`Integer` for non-ties, `Decimal` for ties). Assigning a variant to a calculated column is not possible, so a type conversion is required in that case by using `CONVERT`."](https://dax.guide/medianx/) The same applies to `MEDIAN`.